# perform operations on query results

Tags: sql

I have the following sql query which gives me the days on which every agent was present:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    agent,
    date(login_time) dates
FROM agent_logged_in
WHERE
    date(login_time)>='2017-06-01' AND
    date(login_time)<='2017-06-30'
ORDER BY `agent_logged_in`.`agent` ASC
```

The query gives me output in the following manner:

```
agent dates
name 2017-06-01
name 2017-06-02
```

and so on
I want the output of this code to be like:

```
agent 2017-06-01 2017-06-02 2017-06-03 2017-06-04 ....
name     1         1            1         1    
name2    1         0            1         0
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using

Comment: How to know which date columns to return?

Comment: I'm using mysql with phpmyadmin. I want to display all the dates in the month from 1-30

Comment: You want to use a Pivot

Comment: If I use a pivot, the days like sundays where no entry exists for that date would be skipped right?